# Of course.... Also of course

Tags: phrase-requests

Simply put: do we have a good way of expressing "also of course" when we have two "of course" statements concerning a preceding statement?

---

Not so simply put: "of course" can be useful to express a *concession* (often expressed with "although" and "despite"). Consider:

> Although it means the driving conditions are poor, I am happy to see that it's snowing.

This statement can be expressed using "of course," thus:

> I am happy to see that it's snowing. **Of course**, it means the driving conditions are poor.

This is especially useful when we want to provide additional explanation of the concession:

> I am happy to see that it's snowing. **Of course**, it means the driving conditions are poor. I'm sure the news will be filled with reports of accidents, especially along highway 5a.

And when we do this, we often follow the concession with a reason for our opinion or core statement, as in:

> I am happy to see that it's snowing. **Of course**, it means the driving conditions are poor. I'm sure the news will be filled with reports of accidents, especially along highway 5a. Still, it sure looks beautiful and the holiday season just isn't the same without a fresh blanket of white.

So we have:

**statement** + **concession with "of course"** + **reason or explanation of first statement**

I find this structure quite useful, but occasionally I want to introduce two concessions, and I find myself scratching my head when it comes to introducing the second, as in:

> I am happy to see that it's snowing. **Of course**, it means the driving conditions are poor. I'm sure the news will be filled with reports of accidents, especially along highway 5a. ______________, I'm going to have to spend most of the afternoon shoveling the driveway. That's going to be especially difficult with my lingering back injury. Still, it sure looks beautiful and the holiday season just isn't the same without a fresh blanket of white.

In that blank I am tempted to write "Also of course," but that would sound terribly awkward. Is there a good way to announce a second instance of "of course" in this situation?

Comment: I am happy to see that it's snowing. Of course, there will be two not-so-desirable consequences:

Comment: I think you're confusing *conjunctions* (such as ***although, but***) with adverbial/adjectival terms like ***of course***. There's nothing unusual about, for example, *"I like snow, **although of course** it makes driving more dangerous"*. You can even tack on *"**, naturally**"* there (or use that to replace ***of course***).

Comment: The phrase "Of course" is mostly filler, and is probably best deleted.  In your case, try "I'm *also* going to have to spend ..."  You could also substitute it with a synonymous phrase, such as "This also implies I'm going to have to spend...".  (Or you could quit whining about the shoveling and buy a snow blower.  :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not confused about the difference between conjunctions and adverbial phrases. I'm not equating "although" and "of course" grammatically; but both are used to express concession. In writing, I find "although of course" to be rather clunky, and "naturally" is often used with roughly the same meaning as "of course," but I don't find it appropriate in every situation. Of course, this may be a matter of style, which treads dangerously into opinion-based territory... Still, I'm hoping for a good substitute for "also of course." I realize I may have to settle for "and" or "also."

Comment: @JohnDeters: it was on my wishlist. Alas, more socks.

Comment: @Rusty: I'm a bit confused by your saying you *find "although of course" to be rather clunky*, since it seems like a perfectly natural usage to me. In your given context I'd have thought it's *semantically* the best option, since you want to convey that you *like snow* (implying *snow is good*) whilst acknowledging an obvious downside to snow. That requires a "contrastive" conjunction, since superficially the two statements are incompatible. But if you don't like ***of course*** then ***naturally*** you're free to express it differently (perhaps you might want to rephrase using ***despite***).

Comment: @Fumble. Are you confused or do you simply disagree with its clunkiness? In this context "although" and "of course" can both indicate contrast (in fact, it's "concession"). It's clunky to me because you don't need both. One or the other will do. And I don't dislike "of course." On the contrary: I like it so much I want to use it twice. My question is about expressing the second instance of concession, not generally about how to use conjunctions and adverbial phrases to show contrast.

Comment: Since it does not express a concession by itself, I wouldn't post it as an answer, but "*besides*" sounds to me like a suitable solution in this case. Instead of "adding" another concession, it somehow connects the second one to the first.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: that certainly works here and in many other situations. And it really doesn't require another fully qualified concession expression, but rather an expression of addition that connects it nicely to the "of course" statement. Thanks!

Comment: @Rusty: Of course I disagree that *"although of course"* is "clunky". More to the point though, I think that just because we often introduce terms like ***of course, naturally, obviously*** in contrastive contexts doesn't mean that such terms are inherently contrastive/concessive in and of themselves. You seem to be assigning "meaning by association" here.

Comment: @Fumble: now I'm confused. You are making counterarguments to propositions I've never stated nor implied. When did I suggest that such terms are inherently contrastive/concessive? I presented a very clear context and explanation and asked "what can go in this blank?" With all due respect, none of your comments are germane.

Comment: @Rusty: I'll leave you to it then. I've been trying to understand exactly what you're asking (and why), but I'm obviously getting nowhere. I won't actually closevote just now, but I really can't see where this question is coming from (or where it's going, come to that).

Comment: @Fumble: my attempts to clarify have failed. But I'm heartened by those other comments that demonstrate full understanding of the question.

Comment: You can just use: *Also/Too/As well/Plus/And it goes without saying ;-) /*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep "piling on", there's no need to repeat the *of course*; your statements should naturally associate with your first clause by their nature and your use of various conjunctive constructions:

> I am happy to see that it's snowing.  Of course, it means the driving conditions will be poor.... *It also means that* I'm going to have to spend most of the afternoon shoveling....  *On top of that,* I'll have to restock my store of firewood, which won't be easy with my dull hatchet and a 6-inch hacksaw blade with no handle.  *Furthermore,* I'll have to get my coat patched up, since I put a big hole in it at Halloween.  *Then too,* my poor tiny puppy will be needing a lot more care and attention to make sure he doesn't freeze to death since he only weighs 12 pounds and lost all his fur in a freak dishwasher accident.  *And naturally* I'll also have to go buy a huge truckload of supplies with my back injury and my bad coat and in the middle of all these fender-benders.  *And did I mention* how my bursitis always flares up in cold weather?  Still, it sure looks beautiful and the holiday season just isn't the same without a fresh blanket of white.

Comment: Thanks @Hellion! I like your answer on a couple different levels.

Comment: I count six italicised terms here, only one of which *(naturally)* means the same as *of course*. The others are all different ways of expressing the sense of ***additionally***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, that was my point.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: I *think* I see what you mean, but if you're going to "pile on" multiple "attendant [negative] circumstances" like that, I don't really think it naturally follows that if you introduce the *first* one with something like ***of course***, each subsequent item automatically shares that quality of being "obvious". You could quite reasonably include *...not to mention X*, even if ***X*** is some really obscure additional downside that wouldn't even have occurred to your audience if you hadn't brought it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use as it stands here, although I'm not sure it would be appropriate in a more general case.

I am happy to see that it's snowing. Of course, it means the driving conditions are poor. I'm sure the news will be filled with reports of accidents, especially along highway 5a. **As it stands**, I'm going to have to spend most of the afternoon shoveling the driveway. That's going to be especially difficult with my lingering back injury. Still, it sure looks beautiful and the holiday season just isn't the same without a fresh blanket of white.